# Memory leaks on debug

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have a code that I wrote in C on visual studio.
when I run it on debug mode I get memory leaks, even when I don't use any malloc or calloc or one of those functions, and don't attempt to open any file or directory.
when I run the same code on Release mode however I get no memory Leaks.
I have two questions:

1. what is actually the difference between the two modes
2. why am I getting leaks only on Debug? has someone ever faced this problem? is there something I can do?

Comment: How do you check you get memory leaks?

Comment: I use crtdbg library, and _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() function.
when I run it I get 1 which means I have memory leaks.
however one I do it on Release mode I get 0

Comment: In debug builds a lot of diagnostics are run during the execution of the code. In release builds non eof this checking code is run and therefore no diagnostics are output by `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`.

Comment: so the reason I get 0 on release is that release doesn't really check for memory leaks?

Comment: Not directly related to your question but use https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/ on your code. It will point out issues.